# Determing if a function is analytic on a set

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic on a set $U$.  Let $g(z)=\overline{f(\bar{z})}$.  Is $g(z)$ analytic on $V=\{z\, : \bar{z} \in U\}$.

Is it enough to show this:  $$g'(z)=\lim\limits_{z \to z_0}\frac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0}=\lim\limits_{z \to z_0}\frac{\overline{f(\bar{z})}-\overline{f(\bar{z_0})}}{z-z_0}=\lim\limits_{z \to z_0}\overline{\left(\frac{f(\bar{z})-f(\bar{z_0})}{\bar{z}-\bar{z_0}}\right)}$$

and remark that $f$ is analytic on $U$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is YES!

In particular, the function $g(z)=\overline{f(\bar z)}$ **is** analytic in $V$, while $f(\bar z)$ **is not** analytic on $V$.

Why is $g$ analytic on $V$?

Simply because for every $z_0\in V$ (equivalently $\bar z_0\in U$) the limit
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{z \to z_0}\frac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0} &=\lim\limits_{z \to z_0}\frac{\overline{f(\bar{z})}-\overline{f(\bar{z_0})}}{z-z_0}=\lim\limits_{z \to z_0}\overline{\left(\frac{f(\bar{z})-f(\bar{z_0})}{\bar{z}-\bar{z_0}}\right)}=\lim\limits_{\zeta \to \bar z_0}\overline{\left(\frac{f(\zeta)-f(\bar{z_0})}{\zeta-\bar{z_0}}\right)} \\ &=
\overline{f'(\bar z_0)},
\end{align}
does exist!

Consequently $\big(\overline{f(\bar z)}\big)'=\overline{f'(\bar z)}$.

Note. This is a standard exercise, and one I always ask whenever I teach C.V.

Comment: Correct, but for a student who has just started on analysis you should justify why $z \to z_0$ in the third limit is equivalent to $\zeta \to \overline{z_0}$ in the fourth limit by an epsilon-delta argument, which is why I gave the answer I gave.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not true that $z \mapsto f(\overline{z})$ is analytic on $U$. The expression that you got is the correct way to do it, but now you have to explicitly use differentiability of $f$ at $\overline{z}$, which will give you what you want because the neighbourhood of $\overline{z}$ is the conjugate of the neighbourhood of $z$.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you are saying, if $f$ is differentiable at a point $z$ and if $N(z,\epsilon)$ is a neighborhood about that point, then $f$ is differentiable $\overline{N(z,\epsilon)}$?

Comment: No obviously that's not true. Write out the definition for differentiability: For any $\epsilon>0$, For some $\delta>0$, ... You will find that conjugation behaves nicely with this, and here you are given that $g(z)=\overline{f(\overline{z})}$. What I said was an equivalent more intuitive form which you should draw out, but I didn't say anything about conjugation and differentiability together.

Comment: @user21820: Unfortunately, what you are saying is wrong. $z\mapsto f(\bar z)$ is not analytic, but $z\mapsto \overline{f(\bar z)}$ IS analytic.

Comment: Read what I said carefully. You missed a "not"!

Comment: @user21820 I see what you mean.  I misread it - $N(\bar{z},\epsilon)=\overline{N(z,\epsilon)}$.

Comment: @nhru: Right! That's the key point, which arises from conjugation being just a reflection.

Comment: To make sure I've synthesized everything properly I want to hopefully string together everything that's gone on here.  The equalities I have going on show that $f(\bar{z})$ is analytic on $U$ for $z \in V$.  So $\overline{f(\bar{z})}$ is analytic on $V$ for $z \in V$.

Comment: @nhru: I'm afraid you still don't get the crucial distinction. $z \mapsto f(\overline{z})$ is not analytic on $V$. The most you can say is that $\overline{z} \mapsto f(\overline{z})$ is analytic on $V$, but that is generally not how functions are described. Even then, you cannot get the conclusion from that without looking at the neighbourhoods (or by an epsilon-delta argument).

Comment: If you really want it in one line, $\lim_{z \to z_0} \overline{\left( \frac{f(\overline{z})-f(\overline{z_0})}{\overline{z}-\overline{z_0}} \right)} = \lim_{\overline{z} \to \overline{z_0}} ...$, or what Yiorgos wrote. However, know that the equality depends on what I said, and it can be easy to make mistakes with more complicated substitutions in the limiting variable unless you know what you are doing.